# Other than analytics, what other ways to know whether an app feature is being used

Tags: app, features

I'm new to the community. Hoping to get some advice.

We rolled out an app 4 months ago, and wanted to find out which features from the app that are rarely or never used by the end user.

There are 5 main features, and only 2 have analytics in place.

I'm proposing to the team to conduct user survey, to find out what are the often, rarely, always and never used feature from the end users.

Is there other method that I can explore? other than conducting user survey?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there are other methods. If you can't detect it automatically, than you have to ask them manually. I guess technically a 3rd option could be to remove the features and wait for users to complain, but I wouldn't advise that.

Answer (score 1):

I think a survey, app reviews, and customer support ticket data are great ways to gather that data. Additionally, you could try conducting usability tests, user interviews, and market research.

For usability testing, you could ask your customers to demonstrate how they use the app asking specific questions about what they last used it for, why, and asking them to walk you through it. By doing this, you can better understand what they are doing in the app more frequently. Additionally, you could ask them if they recall any special use cases. Something they only do once in awhile and ask them to show you how they did it, then you can understand if they are able to navigate the app easily. This will allow you to see first hand what users do in your app and also observe the how and why as it may provide insights into what they need and what some of the challenges may be.

User interviews can also provide feedback in the top features because you could ask them more qualitative questions about when they used the apps and why. You can get their thoughts and feelings about what they are doing in the app and perhaps glean insights about what their needs are because they may simply not use other features because they don't know about it or perhaps that's not what they need.

Lastly, market research or competitive analysis can give you broader insights into what is going on in the overall market and how your app competes. This will give you insights into what users may be expecting and how other companies are addressing those needs.

Overall, I think there are many approaches that could give you the insights you need to ensure your app features are useful and desirable to your customers.

Answer (score 0):

There are also things like app reviews that can give you another data point to work with, or perhaps customer support tickets (e.g. a feature is not working or not working well and therefore probably not used).

If you have an in-app feedback mechanism, it may be more accurate than reviews because not all frustrated users will bother to put in a review (depends on the type of app).

If you can also map the end-point of the features and get the stats on them, it will also help piece together the information you need to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, developers are solving this issue with database queries. (SQL, etc.)
For example, they can create a query about how many users performed an action, used a feature, have something attached to their profile, etc. Just ask them to create some for you. It is a cheap and easy method, and in most cases, also out of GDPR regulations because it is not attached to any cookie or third-party data collecting tool.

Answer (score 0):

Analytics, User surveys and user interviews are probably the best ways to garner users perspective of the apps, their pain points and other features required for the next release or for fixing the issues on the present app.

Answer (score 0):

A survey would be nice, especially if you already have their contact info. It's also nice because it provides the number of responses necessary to convince quantitative-inclined stakeholders.

However, to make it more meaningful, consider running 2 surveys: First, ask a long-answer question. Something like "What were you trying to do today? For what reason? How successful were you?" would give you initial qualitative data which can be used as the choices in your second, quantitative survey.

This way, you can come back with not only "Users use X feature the most". But with "Users use X feature the most, while trying to accomplish ABC, and are having problems with DEF." And, to further understand those problems, propose followup usability tests or interviews.